# is it possible to add more join statesments to cdbcriteria yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new in  Yii framework. So my question is, Is it possible to use same property more than one time in a criteria in yii CDbCriteria.

For instance,is it possible to use join property twice in a criteria. Like below example.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->join='LEFT JOIN Client ON Client.id=Invoice.clientId';
$criteria->join='LEFT JOIN User ON User.id=Invoice.clientId';
$criteria->condition='Client.businessId='. Yii::app()->userInfo->business
```

Here I'm talking about any property.

Comment: yes you can use.  Instead of join as above try like this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Comment: @kranthi What if you do not use ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply write every join part as single string:

```
$joins = [];

$joins[] = 'LEFT JOIN Client ON Client.id=Invoice.clientId';

/* ... */

$joins[] = 'LEFT JOIN User ON User.id=Invoice.clientId';

/* ... */

$criteria->join = implode(' ', $joins);
```

---

As you can see from your own code (`$c->join = ''`) you are directly modifying it's `join` parameter, and there is no function to manipulate that. So...

**If** you are using criteria in non-activeRecord way:

Extend this class

```
class DbCriteria extends CDbCriteria {
     public function addJoin($query) {
         /**
          * @look CDbCriteria @line 550
          */
         if($this->join !== $query) {
             if ($this->join === '') {
                $this->join = $query;
             } elseif($query !== '') {
                $this->join .= ' '.query;
             }
          }
     }
}
```

Now you can do

```
$criteria = new DbCriteria();
$criteria->addJoin('LEFT JOIN Client ON Client.id=Invoice.clientId');
$criteria->addJoin('LEFT JOIN User ON User.id=Invoice.clientId');
```

**If** you *are* using ActiveRecord, use [CDbCriteria->with = []](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#with-detail)

```
$criteria->with = [
    'client',
    'user'
];
```

---

**WARNING**

You have invalid Foreign Key. Your `Invoice.client` leads to User **and** to Client tables - and that is against database structure.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I'm asking whether there is a way to use same parameter more than one time in a criteria.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation is great.